# How to trace/log call to each functions in my program?

Tags: delphi

I would like to log in a file all procedure call in my program. Of course I can edit myself each procedure and add in it something like

```
  procedure sample;
  begin
    LogToFile('Enter in procedure sample');
    .....
   end;
```

But off course I would like to do it automatically. Is their any way to do this ?

Comment: What Delphi version?

Comment: @KenWhite : xe2 but i can migrate to Rio no problem I also have the licence

Comment: I'm pretty sure you do NOT want *...to log in a file all procedure call in my program.* Just imagine a sorting routine that calls a comparison routine for each of an array of million records. So somehow you need to write a line of code in those procedures that you are interested in. `CodeSite` is one that shipped with at least some versions of `RAD Studio Professional`. Check it out if it came with your Delphi SKU. Logging can be directed to file in local or remote machine.

Comment: Btw, [CodeSite web site](https://raize.com/codesite/)

Comment: Depending on how serious your need is, you might take a look at the [Quality Suite](https://www.nexusdb.com/support/index.php?q=qualitysuite) from NexusDB.  Whenever I hit a serious performance bottleneck in my code,  the tools in QS let me get to the cause with minimal effort, and it doesn't require any modifications to your code.  It is moderately expensive though.

Comment: This doesn't sound very practical, even if you could achieve it, which you probably can't in any viable way. What actual problem led to you devising this as the solution?

Comment: If you are wanting to log/trace parts of your application I recommend Tracetool https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5498/TraceTool-The-Swiss-Army-Knife-of-Trace